# ASP.NET Error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: c#, asp.net

Cannot figure out where this is coming from,

using the Wingtips Toys tutorial and after restarting my computer it keeps saying this:

The webpage at https://localhost:44300/ErrorPage.aspx?handler=customErrors%20section%20-%20Web.config has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Cleared cookies e.t.c but it still wont budge. Think its coming from Web.Config:

Anyone have an idea?:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!--
   For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
    -->
<configuration>
 <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit           http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
     <section name="entityFramework"       type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework,      Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
<sectionGroup name="elmah">
  <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>
  <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
  <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler,    Elmah"/>
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler,    Elmah"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial      Catalog=aspnet-FingsNTings;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="FingsNTings" connectionString="Data Source=    (LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\FingsNTings.mdf;Integrated Security=True"     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
  <!--
   For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
     <system.Web>
       <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
   <system.web>
   <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx?handler=customErrors%20section%20-     %20Web.config">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="ErrorPage.aspx?     msg=404&amp;handler=customErrors%20section%20-%20Web.config"/>
    </customErrors>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
     <pages>
      <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity"/>
     </namespaces>
      <controls>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms"     namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
       </controls>
    </pages>
    <membership>
      <providers>
       <!--
        ASP.NET Membership is disabled. Please visit the following link         http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support
           -->
         <clear/>
      </providers>
      </membership>
     <profile>
        <providers>
        <!--
        ASP.NET Membership Profile is disabled. Please visit the following link       http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support
       -->
       <clear/>
     </providers>
      </profile>
     <roleManager>
    <!--
           ASP.NET Membership Role is disabled. Please visit the following link      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support
          -->
        <providers>
          <clear/>
          </providers>
          </roleManager>
      <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
           you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
           change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
          of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
  -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
       <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider,        System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
   </providers>
     </sessionState>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
       <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah"/>
        <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>
     </httpModules>
     </system.web>
     <system.webServer>
       <modules>
          <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
        <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
         <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah"  preCondition="managedHandler"/>
     <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
   </modules>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
   <runtime>
     <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral"   publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
       </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
       <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
     </dependentAssembly>
     </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
   <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory,     EntityFramework">
     <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0"/>
      </parameters>
     </defaultConnectionFactory>
     <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"    type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
    <elmah>
   <!--
       See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
       more information on remote access and securing ELMAH.
   -->
    <security allowRemoteAccess="false"/>
 </elmah>
 <location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
       <httpHandlers>
         <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah"/>
      </httpHandlers>
      <!-- 
       See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
        more information on using ASP.NET authorization securing ELMAH.

      <authorization>
       <allow roles="admin" />
        <deny users="*" />  
       </authorization>
  -->
     </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
       <handlers>
       <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory,   Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
     </handlers>
   </system.webServer>
    </location>
   </configuration>
```

Comment: Maybe your error page also throws an error. Can you show the code?

Comment: try running `iisreset`, that should clear it. But I'm wondering if your authorisation is failing and getting stuck in a loop? Have you tried removing the <authorization> block?

Comment: Was due to an issue with The name as I changed it and didn't rename the whole project.